# custom UITableViewCell not occupying the full bound of the cell?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I was doing [this tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/21842/how-to-make-a-gesture-driven-to-do-list-app-part-13) and I couldn't get the results I wanted, in a part of it.

I subclassed the `UITableViewCell` and customized the cell directly because I wanted to add a gradient effect to each cell. Basically, I added gradient effect at the top and bottom of each cell.

Here is the code I have used for it:

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        // add a layer that overlays the cell adding a subtle gradient effect
        gradientLayer = [CAGradientLayer layer];
        gradientLayer.frame = self.bounds;
        gradientLayer.colors = @[(id)[[UIColor colorWithWhite:1.0f alpha:0.2f] CGColor],
        (id)[[UIColor colorWithWhite:1.0f alpha:0.1f] CGColor],
        (id)[[UIColor clearColor] CGColor],
        (id)[[UIColor colorWithWhite:0.0f alpha:0.1f] CGColor]];
        gradientLayer.locations = @[@0.00f, @0.01f, @0.95f, @1.00f];
        [self.layer insertSublayer:gradientLayer atIndex:0];
    }
    return self;
}
-(void) layoutSubviews{
   [super layoutSubviews];

   //ensure that gradient layers occupy the full bounds
   gradientLayer.frame = self.bounds;
}
```

As a desired result, I want to see the gradientLayer occupying the full bounds of the cell. However, it only occupies like 1mm from the start and end of the cell. So, its not occupying the full bounds.

If I comment out the `[super layoutSubviews]` it shows the full gradient, which occupies the full bounds of the cell. But this time, it doesn't show the texts inside the cells.

I couldn't solved it. Any help appreciated.

Comment: what if you call your super layout subviews after settign the gradientLayer.frame?

Comment: Did you try just deleting the layoutSubviews method? In my custom cell, I don't have that method implemented, and the gradient looks fine.

Comment: Can we see the whole class?

Comment: I have already tried what you have suggested. But it didn't work.

Comment: and whole class is like this. nothing more except the import statements. Maybe the problem is somewhere else in the code. however the strange thing is when i remove super layoutSubviews gradient works fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comments below showed that the problem looked like this

[image: this]

And the solution was to set the background of the cell to the clear color.

Comment: how should i implement this code? should i remove initWithStyle and layoutSubviews functions? I am newbie to the iOS, sorry for the simple question. (tried removing them and placing with this code. Still the same result)

Comment: That was the idea. I tested this and it worked. Then again, I also tested your original idea and that also worked. So I am not really sure what causes the gap. It might not even be the cell. Can you set the background to red, remove the gradient and see if the whole table is red?

Comment: I have found the solution in another page. http://fidgetware.com/Tutorials/page2/page2.html "Open the file TableViewTricksViewController.xib in Interface Builder. Select the table view and then open the attributes inspector and change the separator to none and the background color an opacity of zero. Those two settings are shown in the image on the right." it says in this page. did these and now it completely works. But still can someone explain me why it didn't worked before i have changed these. I was removing the seperator line manually in my code.

Comment: You probably have the type set to "plain". I think that type of cell adds a view to the cell that contains the image and the text. That view also uses the background color of the cell. By setting that color to 'clear' the gradient became visible.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to do this is to use self.contentView.frame as follows:

```
gradientLayer.frame = self.contentView.frame;
```